# How to trigger React Hook in Apollo Local State

Tags: react-hooks, apollo, apollo-client, react-cookie

So... I'm using Apollo for local state management in my React app. I'm also using `react-cookie` (which relies on react hooks internally).

I'd like to do something pretty basic:

```
const logout = async (_, args, {cache}) => {
  const cookies = new Cookies()
  cookies.removeCookie (`auth`)
  cache.writeData ({data: {isAuthenticated: false}})
}
```

Problem is since I'm doing this outside a component, I can't use `useCookies` and hence my components never get an update that it's been removed.

Thoughts?

I really don't want to have to choose between putting my state logic into a resolver and using React hooks. And I'm guessing the same thing would apply for redux.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only benefit to having the same state duplicated across both your cookies and component state ([which is what this library does](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/blob/master/packages/react-cookie/src/useCookies.tsx)) is reactivity -- doing so will allow your components to update automatically if the cookies change. If you don't need that functionality, you're better off just using some library that doesn't utilize React-specific features, like [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie). Even if you need to listen for changes in cookies, you can do so without using hooks using a library like [universal-cookie](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie), which is what `react-cookie` uses under the hood.

If you're bent on using `react-cookie`, then your `logout` mutation will need to only update local state, and you'll need to extract the combined logic into a separate hook. Something like:

```
function useLogout = () => {
  const [updateLocalState] = useMutation(LOGOUT_MUTATION)
  const [removeCookie] = useCookies(['auth'])
  return async () => {
    await updateLocalState()
    removeCookie()
  }  
}
```